# Overriding variable creates a NPE when variable is used in the initialization in the super class

Tags: kotlin

Say we have the following set up:

```
open class Foo(open val img: Image) {
    val use = img.graphics
}
class Bar(override val img: BufferedImage) : Foo(img)
```

On initialization, the use of `img.width` creates a NPE. What I think the issue is, is that apparently even though `img` is passed in the constructor of Foo directly in Bar, when it is used in Foo it doesn't point to it, instead it points to the overridden variable in the Bar class. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the fact that the getter of `img` is overridden and returns the value of a different field (since `Bar` overrides `img` with a different type, it requires creating an additional field of type `BufferedImage`). The `Foo` constructor is executed before that field is assigned in `Bar`.

In general, you should avoid using open members in the initialization logic of your classes, because they may be overridden in the subclasses and may rely on some state that, upon the superclass initialization time, is not properly initialized yet.

For your particular case, make `img` in the `Foo` constructor a simple parameter and use the parameter explicitly:

```
open class Foo(img: Image) {
    open val img = img
    val use = img.graphics
}
```